# How to curl a curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

I need to control the curve somehow so it becomes curly in one area and straight in others. It would be also useful to be able to control the radius of the curl and the quantity of the rings. It is important to preserve it as a curve with all the curves object data properties. Any thoughts?

I found an example of what I mean. In this video he controls the curveness of the hair by editing frequency, radius etc. So I need to rectreate this behavior with the regular blender curve. https://youtu.be/U1yG36I70BE

Comment: What you're looking for doesn't exist natively in Blender.  You're talking about procedurally generating the controls of a curve object.  You can do this with scripting.  It's looking like you'll be able to do it with Geometry Nodes in 3.0, based on the notes I've read.

Answer (score 4):

You can hook the curve vertices to empties or bones and scale these empties and bones, you can also keyframe the radius or create empties or bones that will control the radius through drivers etc. Example with a simple hook to empties:

[image]

Comment: No, it is not what I ask. I need a more generative approach: to set for example 10 curl rings along the curve, then smooth it near the tip into a straight line and make it bigger at the start of the curve. I should not create each control point by hand in this case.